# How to properly return an object using operator+ overload function?

Tags: c++

I've created a class which can add two polynomial coefficients, which are simply the numbers in
a dynamic array index positions. My main issue is with the overload+ function return value. Once I add 
two objects of the same class, the Visal Studio will give me an error if I try to return an object 
variable, but if I return the constructor to an object, then the code works fine, and there is no 
error. I don't know why I get this error, as in my previous assignments on dynamic arrays, I was
returning object variables without any problems?  I'm not sure what are the rules on return 
values for the operator+ overload function in this case? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class polynomial
{
public:
  polynomial();
  polynomial(vector<double> vec);
  polynomial(const polynomial& obj);
  void get();
  polynomial& operator=(const polynomial& rightSide);
  friend const polynomial operator +(const polynomial& x, const polynomial& y);
  //The function in question
  ~polynomial() { delete[] p; };
private:
  double *p;
  int expSize;
};


int main() 
{
  vector<double> x(3);
  vector<double>y(3);
  x = { 2,3,4 };
  y = { 4,3,2 };

  polynomial X(x);              //<-- Both objects are constructed with vectors
  polynomial Y(y);

  polynomial obj;
  obj = X + Y;                 //<-- Adding dynamic arrays, and saving the values in obj.

  obj.get();
  cout << endl;

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

polynomial::polynomial()
{
  expSize = 3;
  p = new double[expSize];

  for (int c = 0; c < expSize; c++)
      p[c] = 0;
}

polynomial::polynomial(vector<double>vec)
{   
  expSize = vec.size();

  p = new double[expSize];
  for (int c = 0; c < expSize; c++)                 
      p[c] = 0;                                     
  for (int c = 0; c < expSize; c++)                 
      p[c] = vec[c];                                

}

polynomial::polynomial(const polynomial& obj)
{
  p = new double[expSize];
  for (int c = 0; c < expSize; c++)
      p[c] = obj.p[c];
}

polynomial& polynomial::operator=(const polynomial& rightSide)
{
  if (this == &rightSide)
      return *this;
  else
  {
      expSize = rightSide.expSize;
      delete[] p;
      p = new double[expSize];

      for (int c = 0; c < expSize; c++)
          p[c] = rightSide.p[c];

      return *this;
  }
}

const polynomial operator +(const polynomial& x, const polynomial& y)
{
  polynomial obj;

  if (x.expSize > y.expSize)                //<-- obj.expSize private member variable will 
      obj.expSize = x.expSize;              //    inherit the larger dynamic array index size
  else if(x.expSize <= y.expSize)           //    of the two parameter objects.
      obj.expSize = y.expSize;

  for (int c = 0; c < obj.expSize; c++) {
      obj.p[c] = x.p[c] + y.p[c];
  }
  vector<double>vec(obj.expSize);            //<-- Vector will inherit the new index size too.
  for (int c = 0; c < obj.expSize; c++) {
      vec[c] = obj.p[c];                     //<-- Vector takes joined values of two objects
  }

  //return polynomial(vec);                 //<-- Returning a constructor with vector works fine
  return obj;                              //<-- abort() has been called error
}

void polynomial::get()
{
  for (int c = 0; c < expSize; c++)
      cout << p[c] << endl;
}
```

Comment: FYI, your `operator =` has flaws, and can be written much more easily:  `polynomial& polynomial::operator=(const polynomial& rightSide) { if ( this != &rightSide) { polynomial temp(rightside); std::swap(temp.expSize, expSize); std::swap(temp.p, p); } return *this; }`.  This uses the [copy/swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: `polynomial obj` create an array of 3 items (see default constructor code) and you operator + does not take this into account so you will have undefined behavior in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Typical solution is to implement public `operator+=` as member of your class that
returns non-const reference to `*this` and then `operator+` outside of class using it:

```
inline polynomial operator+(polynomial x, const polynomial& y) {
    x += y;
    return x;
}
```

or same with one line:

```
inline polynomial operator+(polynomial x, const polynomial& y) {
    return x += y;
}
```

The compilers will try to elide as lot of copying or moving as these can in the process.

Note that it can be also written with parameter `x` being reference to const:

```
inline polynomial operator+(const polynomial& x, const polynomial& y) {
    polynomial ret = x;
    ret += y;
    return ret;
}
```

Here we always copy `x` to `ret`. The other variant let caller to move into parameter `x` and so there were more opportunities of optimal usage.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So my question is, to be able to return x += y, doesn't the object x change first before it's being returned, and if it does, than does that mean that we don't need to pass the objects by addresses in parameters to be able to change them?  Hope this question is not too unreasonable.  Thank you.

Comment: I may be misunderstood your question but I added variant where we pass argument by address and explained why it is weaker than accepting argument by value,

Answer (score 1):

I would just make some recommendations. ***copy ctor** of `polynomial`* has a bug. it should be:

```
polynomial::polynomial(const polynomial &obj)
{
  expSize = obj.expSize;
  p = new double[expSize];
  for (int c = 0; c < expSize; c++) p[c] = obj.p[c];
}
```

***overloaded vector ctor*** can be defined like this:

```
polynomial::polynomial(const vector<double> &vec)
{   
  expSize = vec.size();
  p = new double[expSize];
  for (int c = 0; c < expSize; c++) p[c] = vec[c];
}
```

***assignment operator*** can be defined like this:

```
polynomial& polynomial::operator=(const polynomial &rightSide)
{
  if (this != &rightSide)
  {
    //// if two polynomials have the same expSize then
    //// they should have an array of the same size
    if (expSize != rightSide.expSize)
    {
      expSize = rightSide.expSize;
      delete[] p;
      p = new double[expSize];
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < expSize; c++) p[c] = rightSide.p[c];
  }

  return *this;
}
```

***addition operator*** does not need to be a friend; it can be:

```
class polynomial
{
  polynomial operator+(const polynomial &rightSide) const
  {
    //
  }
};
```

but if you must implement it ***as a friend***:

```
polynomial operator+(const polynomial &x, const polynomial &y)
{
  vector<double> vec;
  for (int c = 0; ((c < x.expSize) || (c < y.expSize)); ++c)
  {
    vec.push_back(0);
    if (c < x.expSize) vec.back() += x.p[c];
    if (c < y.expSize) vec.back() += y.p[c];
  }
  //return polynomial(vec); OK
  return vec; // also OK
}
```

Finally, I think you should implement a ***move ctor*** and a ***move assignment operator*** for your class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did write the error in the comment to the right of the return statement in the overload+ function.  The program would compile fine, but on run time it said "abort() has been called", and quit on return statement execution, without displaying the result.  Cheers.

Comment: You nailed it on the first one.  The bug was in the copy constructor, and that's why the program aborted.  I didn't copy the obj.expSize to expSize. A big THANKS.

Comment: @Boksa Good to know it worked. Thanks for asking the question, I'm glad we could help. Cheers.

Comment: `return polynomial(vec);` -- This could simply be `return vec;`

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for that tip.  It is interesting that the compiler knows that when  simply returning a vector, it needs to place it in the constructor parameter of a class object, or did I misunderstand this?

Answer (score 0):

**To quickly answer your question**: *The proper way to return class instances from any function is to return any object supported by the constructor of that class*.

> NB: *polynomials* are best implemented with [sparse arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

The code defined in the following snippet is an ***improvement*** to your `polynomial` class. It is more efficient, it has a *move ctor* and also introduces the concept of a *null array*. Please study carefully.

```
#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H

#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class polynomial
{
private:
  int size;      // size must always be > 0
  double *array; // null value implies, array = [0];

public:
  /*
  1) default ctor
  2) ctor providing support for initializer list : polynomial P = {1, 2, 3};
  3) ctor providing support for STL containers like std::vector<> etc;
  4) copy ctor
  5) move ctor
  */
  polynomial(void);                                                                // (1)
  polynomial(const std::initializer_list<double>&);                                // (2)
  template<template<typename...> class T, typename _Tp> polynomial(const T<_Tp>&); // (3)
  polynomial(const polynomial&);                                                   // (4)
  polynomial(polynomial&&);                                                        // (5)
 ~polynomial(void);

  polynomial& operator=(const polynomial&);
  polynomial& operator=(polynomial&&);
  polynomial& operator=(const std::initializer_list<double>&);
  template<template<typename...> class T, typename _Tp> polynomial& operator=(const T<_Tp>&);

  int order(void) const;
  void clear(void);

  void set(const int &index, const double &value);
  double get(const int &index) const;
  double operator[](const int &index) const;

  polynomial operator+(const polynomial&) const;
  polynomial operator-(const polynomial&) const;

  friend std::basic_ostream<char>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char> &O, const polynomial&);
};

#endif  /* POLYNOMIAL_H */
```

here is an ***example*** that makes use of the `polynomial` class:

```
#include "polynomial.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  polynomial A = {1, 2, 3};
  polynomial B;
  cout << "A: " << A.order() << endl;
  cout << "B: " << B.order() << endl;
  cout << (A + B) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

***output*** is:

```
A: 2
B: 0
3(x^2) + 2x + 1
```

---

**implementation** of *polynomial.cpp*:

```
#include "polynomial.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

polynomial::polynomial(void) : size(1), array(nullptr)
{
  //
}

polynomial::polynomial(const std::initializer_list<double> &args) : polynomial()
{
  if (args.size() > 0) { size = args.size(); array = new double[size]; std::copy(args.begin(), args.end(), array); }
}

template<template<typename...> class T, typename _Tp> polynomial::polynomial(const T<_Tp> &data) : polynomial()
{
  if (data.size() > 0) { size = data.size(); array = new double[size]; std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), array); }
}

polynomial::polynomial(const polynomial &P) : polynomial()
{
    if ((P.array != nullptr) && (P.size > 0)) { size = P.size; array = new double[size]; std::copy(&P.array[0], &P.array[size], array); }
}

polynomial::polynomial(polynomial &&P) : polynomial()
{
  std::swap(size, P.size); std::swap(array, P.array);
}

polynomial::~polynomial(void)
{
  if (array) { delete[] array; array = nullptr; } size = 0;
}

int polynomial::order(void) const
{
  return (size - 1);
}

void polynomial::clear(void)
{
  if (array) { delete[] array; array = nullptr; } size = 1;
}

polynomial& polynomial::operator=(const polynomial &P)
{
  return ((this != &P) ? operator=(polynomial(P)) : (*this));
}

polynomial& polynomial::operator=(polynomial &&P)
{
  if (this != &P) { clear(); std::swap(size, P.size); std::swap(array, P.array); } return (*this);
}

polynomial& polynomial::operator=(const std::initializer_list<double> &args)
{
  return operator=(polynomial(args));
}

template<template<typename...> class T, typename _Tp> polynomial& polynomial::operator=(const T<_Tp> &data)
{
  return operator=(polynomial(data));
}

void polynomial::set(const int &i, const double &d)
{
  if ((size < 1) || (i < 0) || (i >= size)) throw "index out of bounds!";
  if (array == nullptr) { array = new double[size]; } array[i] = d;
}

double polynomial::get(const int &i) const
{
  if ((size < 1) || (i < 0) || (i >= size)) throw "index out of bounds!";
  return ((array == nullptr) ? 0 : array[i]);
}

double polynomial::operator[](const int &i) const
{
  return get(i);
}

polynomial polynomial::operator+(const polynomial &B) const
{
  std::list<double> data;
  auto &A = (*this);

  for (int i = 0; ((i < A.size) || (i < B.size)); ++i)
  {
    data.push_back(0);
    if (i < A.size) data.back() += A.get(i);
    if (i < B.size) data.back() += B.get(i);
  }

  return data;
}

polynomial polynomial::operator-(const polynomial &B) const
{
  std::list<double> data;
  auto &A = (*this);

  for (int i = 0; ((i < A.size) || (i < B.size)); ++i)
  {
    data.push_back(0);
    if (i < A.size) data.back() += A.get(i);
    if (i < B.size) data.back() -= B.get(i);
  }

  return data;
}

std::basic_ostream<char>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char> &O, const polynomial &P)
{
  if ((P.array != nullptr) && (P.size > 0))
  {
    std::basic_stringstream<char> sout;

    sout.precision(O.precision());

    sout.flags(sout.flags() | (O.flags() & std::ios::floatfield));

    for (int i = (P.size - 1), j = 0; (i >= 0); --i, ++j)
    {
      if (j == 0) sout << P.array[i];
      else sout << ((P.array[i] < 0) ? " - " : " + ") << std::abs(P.array[i]);
      if (i >= 2) sout << "(x^" << i << ')';
      if (i == 1) sout << 'x';
    }

    O << sout.str();
  }
  else
  {
    O << 0;
  }

  return O;
}
```

I hope this is helpful

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely look it up, since it correlates to what I am working on at the moment. The book did mention sparse matrix techniques with missing terms, but for the moment I concentrated on creating my own polynomial Class with some addition, multiplication, etc.

Comment: @Boksa Thank you for the question. I can't recall any book on polynomials right now. But when you have the chance, you can research _published academic papers_ on the subject. Also _polynomials with sparse vectors_ are so easy, you can actually implement it on your own. All the best.